# Make Eclipse list (only) all enum entries on assignment of variable of enum type

Tags: c, eclipse, autocomplete, enums, assign

The Eclipse `<CTRL>+<SPACE>` code completion assist feature doesn't work with enums the way I want to. Can anyone tell me how to configure it so that I get the follow:

In my C (not C++) project I'm using typedef enums and would like that Eclipse provides a list of all enum entries on `<CTRL>+<SPACE>` (or maybe another key combination) if I'm typing an assignment of a variable of this enum type.

Example:

```
typedef enum {
   CONSTANT_A = 0,
   CONSTANT_B = 1,
   CONSTANT_C = 2,
} myenumtype_t;

void func(void)
{
  myenumtype_t myenumvar;

  myenumvar = <CTRL>+<SHIFT>
}
```

It should list CONSTANT_A, CONSTANT_B, CONSTANT_C and allow me to choose one.
If it's list other enum variables of the exact same enum type then this is also ok, but I don't like any other variable in the suggestion list.

However, at the moment my Eclipse is listing basically all global and local variables indendent of their type, which isn't very useful.

PS: My Eclipse variant is Arctic Studio 5.0.0 which is basically Eclipse CDT 8.3.0.

Comment: You don't have any progress on this, have you?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but definitely serves the purpose.

You can type a clue, may be "CON" in your specific case, and then press ctrl + space